# MeteorJS: Restful API works at Meteor Shell but not Meteor Methods

Tags: api, rest, meteor

I am using the HTTP.call to make Restful API calls to a third party service provider.

I created relevant Meteor Methods at the server side and call them from the client.

I have no problem for the GET calls. However for POST and PUT calls, it returns Internal server error (500) at client and a 405 Method not allowed at server.

When I tried debugging it, I opened Meteor Shell and calling the POST and PUT calls there, they work. But they don't when I call the methods from client.

Client side I have...

```
Meteor.call('cancelCall', function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

And Server side...

```
Meteor.methods('cancelCall', function () {
 var url = 'http://example.com/some/params/cancel';
 var result = HTTP.call('PUT', url);
 return result;
});
```

What I type directly to Meteor Shell...

```
HTTP.call('PUT', 'http://example.com/some/params/cancel');
```

What's causing this behaviour and how to fix it?

Many thanks.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace/paren in your example code above

Comment: thanks, that was just my typo

Comment: This all looks right to me. I'm assuming you are only defining the method on the server, right?

Comment: @ChristianFritz yes, the methods were defined from server and calling from client. Can't get to know why it works in Meteor shell only

Comment: Can you provide the error / returned values from calling them in the browser console?

Comment: M…r.m…e.errorClass {error: 500, reason: "Internal server error", details: undefined, message: "Internal server error [500]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping these calls in methods is unnecessary, as HTTP.call (and associated methods) can be called directly on the client.

[Docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call):  The call signature looks like this:

> HTTP.call('PUT', url, [callOptions], [asyncCallback])

On the server you can omit the asyncCallback parameter, and the call simply blocks until it has a result.

On the client this cannot be omitted, as only async calls are possible.

Also you are not providing any data for the PUT (/POST) method.  This should be passed in the callOptions parameter like this:

```
HTTP.call('PUT', url, {params: {user: userId}}, callbackFunc)
```

Comment: Everything you say is true, but I don't think it answers the question.

Comment: OK so there is a mix of advice (you don't need to use Meteor.method for this), and and a possible solution (you need to provide params via the callOptions parameter, rather than as part of the url).

Comment: I guess if accessing an api that does not provide CORS headers a Meteor.method is an acceptable workaround

Comment: I can run PUT call in Meteor Shell without the params, given the fact that the path has params in the middle of the link and it ends with /cancel. On the other hand, I can run POST call with setting header and content, but again, it only works in the shell

Answer (score 0):

> However for POST and PUT calls, it returns Internal server error (500)
>   at client and a 405 Method not allowed at server.

When you make POST and PUT requests server side you are getting Error 405 returned.  That tells you that the api you are calling does not accept POST and PUT requests.

This part is a guess:

When you make these same requests from the client via Meteor.method calls, your app server is making the request, and getting 405 errors from the remote server.  This then causes your server to return 500 (Internal Server Error) back to the client.

Comment: However I can run POST & PUT in Meteor Shell, it also works at Advanced Rest Client (the Chrome extenstion) and Postman. And these calls are based on the API document provided by our partner.

Comment: So when did you get the 405?

Comment: At browser console, calling the Meteor Method at server side, it returns 405 (terminal), 500 (browser console)